# How to get a file name from a file pointer to pointer. (FILE **inputFile)

Tags: c, file

I'm writing a function to read a file, and we are required to pass the function a pointer to pointer (FILE **file). I am just trying to get the file name from this but am a little lost on how I would go about that.

If that wasn't clear at all please let me know and thanks in advance

Comment: There's no standard way to do this. There might not even be a filename, e.g. if the `FILE*` was created using `popen()` or `fdopen()`.

Comment: The language is in the `c` tag, you don't need to say it in the question. Also, `FILE *` is only a C concept.

Comment: Why do you think you need to get the filename in order to read the file?

Comment: My bad I'm new to asking questions on stackoverflow. I only thought of this way because it's what i have been taught thus far. Do you have a suggestion on another way I could read the file?

Comment: Use `*file` to read the file.

Comment: you need a filename in order to read a file, that is (almost always) true. That filename is a parameter in the `fopen()` function. This returns a `FILE *` that you will be using for the rest of your code to read and/or write to your file. Is your question, how do you read a file in C, in general?

Comment: Is the function supposed to open the file? Then you need to pass the filename as a separate argument. Then use `*file = fopen(filename, "r");`

Comment: You need to provide more details about what you're trying to do. As it is, this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Sorry about that. I am required to read a csv file line by line, we are given the prototype "record_t read_csv_record(FILE **csvfile)" . I am confused on how i would go about doing that, given that the argument is **csvfile.

Comment: @iSERVO, now it is clearer: The type of the argument of the prototype indicates that the file is already opened with `fopen()` before the call of `read_csv_record()`. That means that you shoud call `fopen()` with the appropriate filename first to get a `FILE *` handler to the opened file and then pass that handler (or rather, its address given the presence of the double `*`) as an argument to `read_csv_record()`

Comment: Are you sure it's `FILE **csvfile` and not `FILE *csvfile`? If it's `FILE *csvfile`, you can assume the file has already been opened, and you don't need the name. If it's `FILE **csvfile`, it may be that you need to open it by passing `*csvfile` to `fopen()` -- and in that case you do need the name, but I don't see how you could get it. The requirements you were given may or may not be sufficiently clear. The subset of those requirements that you've shown us certainly are not.